# WPF Datagrid cell tooltip

Tags: wpf, datagrid, linq-to-entities, tooltip

I have a WPF 4.0 `DataGrid` displaying data from a `LINQ to Entities` query. The query returns an anonymous list so the `DataGrid` has its `AutoGenerateColumns` property set to true.
How can I display `ToolTips` for the column cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably do this in the column's style. If you want to choose the style at runtime, you can subscribe to the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event, and customize the column as you like...

Here is a link from on MSDN with a very good tutorial on [Customizing AutoGenerated Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I finally figured out how to use a style setter dynamically for a tooltip in the AutoGeneratingColumn event.